# Protect Windows core processes

Tags: windows, security

Microsoft Defender included an option to isolate Windows kernel. That feature is not compatible with some device drivers ( in my case, video drivers ) . My question is, is there a way to do it other than Microsoft Defender? The goal is to protect system processes from being accessed when they shouldn't. using an antivirus is not an option but I'm open to other security tools

Comment: Windows Defender (post Windows 10 V1803) employs Microsoft Enhanced Mitigation Experience Tool (EMET). This is an excellent kernel protection and threat protection tool. I am not even sure if you can disable EMET. Have you explained this to your video card manufacturer?  EMET and then base Windows Defender should not be disabled.

Comment: Nvidia and AMD drivers are both fully compliant with the Windows Display Model and thus Microsoft Defender

Comment: We have Nvidia and Intel drivers and Windows Defender does not cause issues anywhere for us either - all clients with this kind of setup

Comment: System processes cannot be accessed when they shouldn't. What are you protecting them from, yourself?